OpenAPI (Dart): Prevent automatic response wrapping with ABP structure
I'm using the OpenAPI Generator to generate a Dart client. My API responses are being automatically wrapped in an ABP-style structure, which I don't want. I'm expecting a simple JSON response, but instead, it's nested under a result field within a larger object.
Expected Response (Example):
{  "state": 1,   "tenantId": 0,   "serverRootAddress": "string",   "apiUrl": "string",   "dnsUrl": "string" } 

Actual Response (Example):
{   "result": {     "state": 1,     "tenantId": 123,     "serverRootAddress": "google.com",     "apiUrl": null,     "dnsUrl": null   },   "targetUrl": null,   "success": true,   "error": null,   "unAuthorizedRequest": false,   "__abp": true }

this wrapping occurs for all API responses. The wrapping structure looks like this:
{
  "result": Schema?,
  "targetUrl": string?,
  "success": bool,
  "error": ErrorModel?,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": bool,
  "__abp": bool
}

How can I configure the OpenAPI Generator (or modify the generated code) to prevent this automatic wrapping and receive the direct JSON response as defined in my OpenAPI specification? I'm using the Dart client generator. My OpenAPI specification (YAML or JSON) is available upon request. (Please provide a link to a gist or paste a simplified version if possible).
